# Unknown class GPPSignInButton in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, google-plus, sign

When integrating google+ in my iOS app, this error always occur after linking from storyboard to the  GPPSignInButton!! Any solutions plz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow the line by line code from this page
 https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started 
 and update your Build Settings with

```
-all_load -ObjC
```

in Other linker flags

Comment: Thank You So Much.. You saved my life :)